# Multiple axios calls in single route call: error: can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, jira-rest-api

I've read all the threads on stack I could find regarding this error, and while I have learned a lot about what could possibly be wrong conceptually, nothing I've applied from that learning has worked yet.

The problem is, in my app.get (using express) for the index page I first do an axios post for basic auth to the Jira Api. Then in the same .get method I do an axios get with an initial query I'd like to run. I am not explicitly setting headers again in this call, but when I try to render my results, I get the error. If I take out the res.render calls from my axios.get method, the rest of my script works fine.

I have tried to move all renders to a single render still in the app.get method, but outside of any promise callbacks from my axios calls. At that point my variables I set are undefined (I believe they're not being returned from the promise the way I want. It's not still in my code, but I have tried explicitly returning my variables inside my promise, but that doesn't work. I've also tried to return the entire axios.post function, no dice).

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const axios = require('axios');
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app = express();

app.engine('.hbs', hbs({defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  const username = "jirauser";
  const password = "jirapassword"

  axios.post('https://myjirainstance.atlassian.net', {
    username: username,
    password: password,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString('base64'),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then (response => {
    // console.log(res);
    const message = response.data;
    message;
    res.render('index', {
      message: "you're logged in"
    });
  }).catch(function(error) {
    authError = error;

    res.render('index', {
      error: error
    })
  });

  return axios.get('https://jamfsoftware.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=carlton.brumbelow')
  .then (response => {
    console.log(response);

    queryResponse = 'your query was successful'

  }).catch( error => {
    console.log(error);

    queryError = error

  });

  // res.render('index', {
  //   message: message,
  //   authError: authError,
  //   queryResponse: queryResponse,
  //   queryError: queryError
  // })

})



app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: That's because you've already sent your response using `res.render`.

Comment: By which I assume now you can't send multiple responses?

Comment: If that's the case, then was I on the right track when I attempted to send a single response following both of my axios calls? And if so, how do I get the data returned in a promise accessible to the rest of my script? Returning the variables directly in my then() didn't work, and returning the entire axios.get/axios.post functions did not work either.

Comment: Nope, each route has a single response. Actually, there are multiple ways to fix this. For example, you could stop the execution of your function when you use `res.render` so you're sure you cannot send another response. In your case, I would track if there is an error that happened in a catch block and just store it in a variable then, in the end, just check if everything worked fine and send the response.

Comment: And FYI I don't think you need to return anything in your route's callback :)

Comment: And last but not least, don't forget you're using async actions, so you'll need to wait for all promises to check if an error happened (with `async/await` or `promise.all`).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help out. I'll try your suggestions here in a bit and see if I can figure it out.